# What is imageData in JSON file which comes from labelme tool?

Tags: data-annotations

I am trying to convert **VIA (VGG Image Annotator) JSON file** to **Labelme JSON file**, but the only problem is imageData attribute in Labelme. I am not able to upload my JSON file into Labelme tool without imageData. Does Anyone has idea how to get imageData or anything which is useful to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

You were just not lucky enough to find this in Google :) . The functions can be found in , [LabelMe's sources](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/blob/1d6ea6951c025a7db0540c7eac77577bc1507efa/labelme/utils/image.py#L10):

```
def img_b64_to_arr(img_b64):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_b64))
    img_arr = np.array(PIL.Image.open(f))
    return img_arr

def img_arr_to_b64(img_arr):
    img_pil = PIL.Image.fromarray(img_arr)
    f = io.BytesIO()
    img_pil.save(f, format='PNG')
    img_bin = f.getvalue()
    if hasattr(base64, 'encodebytes'):
        img_b64 = base64.encodebytes(img_bin)
    else:
        img_b64 = base64.encodestring(img_bin)
    return img_b64
```

I had problems with theirs if hasattr(base64, 'encodebytes'):..., it generates superfluous \n and b' ', so I rewrote the second one as

```
import codecs

def encodeImageForJson(image):
    img_pil = PIL.Image.fromarray(image, mode='RGB')
    f = io.BytesIO()
    img_pil.save(f, format='PNG')
    data = f.getvalue()
    encData = codecs.encode(data, 'base64').decode()
    encData = encData.replace('\n', '')
    return encData
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you shoud install `labelme`, then try the following:

```
data = labelme.LabelFile.load_image_file(img_path)
image_data = base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8')
```

Output is the same as JSON file by manual.

Comment: You are a life saver ;>

Answer (score 2):

It is called base64 type of an image, you can turn image into base64 data by the following code:

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode(open(img_path, "rb").read())
print(encoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:
Set the imageData to "null"
Also don't forget to pass the path in imagePath.